# Linear operator that commutes with projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T, \pi$ be linear operators on a vector space $V$. If $\pi$ is a projection and $T\pi = \pi T$, does it follow that $\pi \in F[T]$, i. e. $\pi$ can be written as a polynomial in $T$?

I know that the kernel and range of $\pi$ would be $T$ invariant, but can't figure out where to go from here.

Comment: Isn't $T(x,y)=(x,0)$ and $\pi(x,y)=(0,y)$ a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $I:V\rightarrow V$ be the identity map. Let $\pi$ be a non-trivial projection (we assume that $\mbox{dim}(V) \geq 2$). Then $\pi$ commutes with $I$. However, $\pi$ cannot be written as a polynomial of $I$.